# Pyodbc: Error while connecting to Vertica

Tags: python, pyodbc, vertica

I'm using pyodbc to connect to vertica using a DSN.

I have the related information in .odbc.ini and .vertica.ini files.

When I try to connect to Vertica using pyodbc,

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, May 11 2015, 13:38:47)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=vertica")
```

I get the below error:

```
 Sep 14 02:30:16 INFO  1700620032 VMetadataSource::Execute: Command status: SELECT, 0 tuples 19 fields
 Sep 14 02:30:16 INFO  1700620032 Connection::ExecuteCatalogFunction: SQLGetTypeInfo
 Sep 14 02:30:16 ERROR 1700620032 Statement::ExecuteCatalogFunction: [DSI] The error message InvalidCursorState could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that /opt/vertica7/lib64/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml exists.
 Sep 14 02:30:16 INFO  1700620032 Connection::ExecuteCatalogFunction: SQLGetTypeInfo
 Sep 14 02:30:16 ERROR 1700620032 Statement::ExecuteCatalogFunction: [DSI] The error message InvalidCursorState could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that /opt/vertica7/lib64/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml exists.
```